# Angulars - Choose which version of angularjs Yeoman must install

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, scaffolding

My question is very basilar, but I didn't found anything in the web: how can I tell Yeoman to use a specific version of Angularjs instead of the latest available?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry... but why should you ever want to scaffold a new app using an oudated version of a library?

Comment: @MarcoS It's a requirements for a prject, not a choice of mine..

Comment: I see... See my answer for an answer... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force Angular's requested version in generated `bower.json` file, and then running `bower install`...
Then please be sure all other dependencies in `bower.json` file are not broken by the previous downgrade, possibly downgrading other libraries versions, too...